# Maximum Adverse Excursion Formula - Short Trade Position?

Tags: trading, risk-management, algorithmic-trading, short-selling, money-management

Is the formula for the Maximum Adverse Excursion for a Short Selling Trade the (Open - High) / Open, or (High - Open) / Open ?

Comment: The MAE is a kind of potential loss or drawdown that is usually shown as positive. I.e. 5 means you could have lost 5 dollars. So on a shortsale, if done in percentage terms, it would be (high-open)/open and on a buy (open-low)/open.

Comment: @noob2 , great !, thanks for that.  On the shortsale side, formula for this is not displayed much out there.